# Local mail server not sending emails

Tags: email, fedora, smtp

Ever since the `ISP` was changed, I am  having issues with our `local mail server (Fedora/sendmail)`. The log states `connection timed out with domain.com` when I try to send test mail  to `abc@domain.com`. But I can successfully `ping domain.com` from the `Fedora` box. It's hosted by a third party web hosting site. When I send the test message, I get the `Message accepted for delivery` response from the mail server but it never gets delivered. I think some setting is missing somewhere and I am a `Linux newbie`. Please advice.

`Port 25` is open and listening. The smtp server receives incoming mails though. But can't send out emails.

Answer (score 0):

Can you telnet smtp port on host.domain.com host? Do you get SMTP greeting message?

```
telnet host.domain.com 25
```

**NO** => Your outgoing smtp connections may be blocked (by your ISP) to stop outgoing spam.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably it. Configure the system to use a different port for secure send (587, or for SMTP-SSL use 465). 25 is blocked by pretty much EVERY ISP as an unsecured relay mostly used for spam these days.

Comment: @Andrzej A. Filip : Thanks for the response. Seems like that's the problem.  I tried changing the sendmail port to 587 using the sendmail.mc file and restarted the service. How do I add the port to iptables to bypass the firewall? I am using Fedora 3 version installed over 10 years ago.

Comment: @dr.nixon : So I ended up calling ISP and they unblocked the port 25. Now I can send test messages successfully using Outlook to the mail server and subsequently receive it on my email address. But when I try to test the mail server directly from the machine, for some reason the relay is root@localhost compared to relay =abc.com using Outlook. abc.comis our external smtp server, its defined in etc/hosts, sendmail.mc etc. but still its not resolving it properly. Any tips?

Comment: What is reported by commands `hostname` and `hostname --fqdn`?

Comment: @AndrzejA.Filip : I fixed it. Some how my loopback adapter was turned off and hence it wasn't resolving the names properly. Once I turned it back ON, now it works.